# Finding elements in Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

My button looks like this:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-order-export" data-backdrop="false" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
    <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> 엑셀 저장
</button>`
```

How can I click this object via selenium to automate some work? I tried:

`driver.find_element_by_link_text('엑셀 저장').click()`

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: @TylerH you can use python with `selenium `or i would say it is recommended with Python

Comment: @PaulNicolashunter Yes but what does *this question* have to do with Python? Seems like he is in a pure Selenium scenario for the scope of this problem.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I'm using python to take control of several different websites including stuffs I wrote here and also I will collect and combine the data from each websites after i sucess automation. And also, will make private website via Flask to take control of them. In summary, to build a control center website of sereral target websites.

Comment: @TylerH the way he intended to find the method is pretty much indicating how we use methods in python. OR the answer he want is in `Python` and not `Java`

Answer (score 0):

You could take its xpath by right-clicking the element in developer tools and choosing copy. Then just find the element using xpath.

Comment: I already tried it but failed. However, with Firefox addon, I found

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='content-wrapper']//button[normalize-space(.)='엑셀 저장']").click()

works just fine.

Thank you for your kind answer

Answer (score 0):

The `WebElement` which you are trying to search/find is within `<button>` tag hence `find_element_by_link_text` may not work. We will be using an `xpath` to locate the `WebElement` as follows:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-default btn-sm']/i[@class='fa fa-file-excel-o']").click()
```